# Mssql bit type to c# bool (or string) type

Tags: c#

I've ran into an unexpected odd issue with types between mssql and c#. My dbo has several fields that are `bit` type, for me to store true/false values.

My API retrieves through this controller:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> GetUserRoles([FromBody] UserRolesID userID)
        {
            string UserID = userID.UserID.ToString();
            UserRoles userRoles = _apiKeyService.GetUserRoles(UserID);
            if(userRoles != null)
            {
                var ReturnString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userRoles);
                return Ok(ReturnString);
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest("No roles found");
            }
        }
```

This is the service method that feeds the controller:

```
        {
            var query = (from u in _dbContext.UserRoles
                         where u.UserID == userID
                         select new UserRoles());
            return query.First();
        }
```

And this is the UserRole wrapper:

```
    {
        public string UserID { get; set; } = "";
        public bool Appointment_View { get; set; }
        public bool Appointment_Modify { get; set; }
        public bool Foster_View { get; set; }
        public bool Foster_Modify { get; set; }
        public bool Dog_View { get; set; }
        public bool Dog_Modify { get; set; }
        public bool Rules_View { get; set; }
        public bool Rules_Modify { get; set; }
        public bool User_Approve { get; set; }
        public bool User_Modify { get; set; }
    }
```

The response Im getting from my API is:

```
{"UserID":"","Appointment_View":false,"Appointment_Modify":false,"Foster_View":false,"Foster_Modify":false,"Dog_View":false,"Dog_Modify":false,"Rules_View":false,"Rules_Modify":false,"User_Approve":false,"User_Modify":false}
```

This is the right format, right field names, except the values aren't correct. For the sake of testing, each field alternates between true/false in the dbo. I haven't made any changes to the data at all during the transmission, so Im very confused. I've never worked with the `bit` type before.

Comment: Why are you manually serializing userRoles to JSON? Let the framework serialize it for you. Is this ASP.NET or is it ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @mason I actually only just discovered while trying to figure this out, that the framework does it for you. I was unaware up until then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your LINQ query that's getting the data. You're selecting a new UserRoles, but you're not setting any of the values on the UserRoles you've created. That you're getting back an empty user. It's got nothing to do with the bit to boolean translation. Notice how the UserID is an empty string as well?

I don't write the LINQ syntax style that you're using, but here it is in the method style:

```
return _dbContext.UserRoles.First(ur => ur.UserID == userId);
```

Notice that the where clause you were using to filter can just be combined directly with the First extension method.

Comment: That was it. I had not really considered what I was doing with that linq statement, I did notice the empty UserID but that was in the peripheral honestly. Makes a world of sense now. I just saw data and ran with it until I was getting unexpected results down the line. Cheers!